# Intern 4 tests fail to load the Dojo2 loader

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, intern

I'm migrating from Intern 3/requirejs to Intern 4/dojo2. I'm trying to run a test and immediately after the capabilities checks it will fail before ever loading my tests with this error:

```
Listening on localhost:9000 (ws 9001)
Tunnel started

‣ Created remote session chrome 66.0.3359.139 on XP (bc531663-f9f7-4cba-9038-6ab15808e9a0)
Suite chrome 66.0.3359.139 on XP FAILED
Error: Unable to load /..\node_modules\intern/loaders/dojo2.js
  at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous>  <node_modules\intern\browser\remote.js:667:23264>
TOTAL: tested 1 platforms, 0 passed, 0 failed; suite error occurred
```

It's 404ing on that file from `http://localhost:9000/__intern/browser/remote.html` because it's trying to get dojo2.js from the wrong path by the looks of it. If I replace `dojo2` in my config script with `__intern/loaders/dojo2.js` it will then 404 on `/node_modules/@dojo/loader/loader.js`. It looks like it's just looking for the wrong paths, is there something I can do to fix this?

intern.json

```
{
    "loader": {
        "script": "dojo2",
        "config": {
            "waitSeconds": 60,
            "packages": [ {
                    "name": "objects",
                    "location": "objects"
                }, {
                    "name": "edits",
                    "location": "./",
                    "main": "edits"
                }, {
                    "name": "prepare",
                    "location": "TESTS",
                    "main": "prepare"
                }, {
                    "name": "common",
                    "location": "./",
                    "main": "common"
                }, {
                    "name": "socket",
                    "location": "http://localhost:2020/socket.io",
                    "main": "socket.io"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "suites": [
        "./functional/InitTests.js"
    ],
    "environments": [ {
            "browserName": "chrome"
        }
    ],
    "tunnelOptions": {
        "drivers": [
            "chrome"
        ],
        "port": 4444,
        "version": "3.4.0",
        "maxConcurrency": 1,
        "runnerClientReporter": {
            "writeHtml": false
        }
    },
    "tunnel": "null",
    "leaveRemoteOpen": true,
    "grep": ""
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few potential issues:

- Have you installed `@dojo/loader`? The loader scripts require that the associated loader be installed as a peer of Intern.
- When using an AMD loader, specify tests as module IDs rather than file names
- Does `./functional/InitTests.js` actually contain functional tests? If so, it should be specified under `functionalSuites`.

Comment: The issue was suites vs functionalSuites. Thank you! Is `suites` only for unit test suites then?

Comment: Yes, `suites` is for unit tests and `functionalSuites` is for functional tests. The two types look very similar when written, but only functional tests are given a `remote` object, and functional tests are always run in a Node environment.

Comment: If I put unit test paths in a `suites` array like in the OP should that work as is? I'm running into the same issue with unit tests now by doing that.

Comment: `suites` is for unit tests, `functionalSuites` is for functional tests.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant for running unit tests with webdrivers, not by accessing the browser runner.

Comment: Is there anything special that has to be done to get unit tests to run with selenium?

Comment: No, just specify a browser in your environments list and provide some unit test suites in `suites`. You might also have an easier time using the `selenium` tunnel rather than `null`; it will automatically download and start up Selenium, and will also grab chromedriver. `tunnelOptions` doesn't actually do anything with the `null` tunnel.